# font alignment off

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, styles

I am expecting two different font styles on the same row in a grid to be aligned at the bottom of the grid row but as you can see, it isn't happening!

Does anyone see what I need to change?

Cheers,
Beryl

## the problem

[image]

## the grid

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource SubjectStyle}" .../>
        ...
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DisplayNameStyle}" .../>
        ...
</Grid>
```

## subject style

```
<Style x:Key="SubjectStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
</Style>
```

## displayName style

```
<Style x:Key="DisplayNameStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Label` has a default `Padding` of 5. The `TextBlock's` default `Padding` is 0. Just add a setter for the `Padding` property in the style.

Answer (score 1):

Bring it up at runtime in Chrome and F12 it to inspect the elements. It's possible there's some margin or other issue affecting Labels that isn't affecting your text block.

Additionally: Why Label, and not TextBlock for both?

Worst case, slap a Margin in one or the other to ensure they line up pretty and verify across browsers.

Comment: Note that the poster is using WPF, so Chrome debug tools don't apply. However, the margin style is still applied in a similar manner.

Comment: I originally used a Label to make it easier to get at the Access Text. Cheers